# How to get parameters and theirs values from ParametersPanel in PerpetuumSoft.ReportViewer?

Tags: silverlight, reporting-services, reportviewer

I use [PerpetuumSoft.ReportViewer for SSRS 2008](http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/Silverlight-Viewer-for-Reporting-Services.aspx).

I need to list of parameters and theirs values that user set in ParametersPanel.

I watch ReportViewer.Parameter but it just get me parameters that I add handy to it in code but I need to parameters that set by user in ParametersPanel.

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The report viewer have an event that fire when set parameter button clicked. In handler of this event we can get all parameters and their values and store in a collection to use every where that we need.

```
<rpt:ReportViewer x:Name="reportViewer" 
     ParametersProcessing="reportViewer_ParametersProcessing"/>

public List<ReportParameterValue> ReportParameterValues { get; set; }
private void reportViewer_ParametersProcessing(object sender, ParametersProcessingEventArgs e)
{
    ReportParameterValues = e.Collection;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find more information here: [How to check the parameters values input by the user in the parameters toolbar](http://helpcenter.perpetuumsoft.com/KB/a273/how-to-check-parameters-values-input-the-user-the.aspx)